# Error Call to undefined function collect() using C

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I get an error in my collection, and I don't know how to fix it.

> Call to undefined function collect()

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Illuminate\Support\Collections;

class CityAnalyzer
{
    private $cityData;

    public function __construct($cityData)
    {
        $this->$cityData = $cityData;
    }
    
    public function printHighestPopulatedCities()
    {
        $sortedDescendingCityData = collect($this->$cityData)
            ->map(function ($city) {
                
            return new City($city["place_name"], $city["total_population_2010"]);
        })->sortByDesc('population')->values()->all();

        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            echo "$sortedDescendingCityData[$i]\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your "require" at the top of this class is weird for a Laravel class. Also, you should not use `$` char after `$this->`.

Comment: You don't need to `use Collections`, the collect function isn't under the namespace and is available globally after the package is installed.

Comment: Given what I wrote earlier, have you run `composer install` to make sure that the package is installed.

Comment: Where did you define that method? How is this question related to Composer?

Comment: @NicoHaase `collect` is defined in the `illuminate/collections` package, hence why OP added the composer tag.